# Refresh Page using Angular Js, Oauth 2.0 and GAE as my backend and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, google-app-engine, oauth

Hello all i am new into web development, i have created a simple single page application using bootstrap, angular Js. I have used Oauth 2.0 for Google+ login authentication and Google app engine as my backend. The problem is when i login from the login page and route to different HTML pages it works well and fine, But when i am in a particular WebPage and try to reload the page, the oauth authentication is lost and my google+ User object returns me null in the endpoints. My Index.html page looks like below

```html
<script>
        /**
         * Initializes the Google API JavaScript client. Bootstrap the angular module after loading the Google libraries
         * so that Google JavaScript library ready in the angular modules.
         */
         function init() {
          gapi.client.load('mygaeendpoint', 'v1', null, '//'+                        
                           window.location.host'/_ah/api');
  
           gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
              angular.bootstrap(document, ['myangularApp']);                             });   
         };
    </script>
    <script src="//apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=init"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="RootCtrl" ng-init="initSignInButton()">
  
  
     <ng-view></ng-view>
```

So when i reload a page it comes to this page reinitializes the oauth and all my tokens are lost and redirects me to login page. I dont know what mistake i am doing. Please help me out on this.

Comment: Consider using a persistent store like localStorage to store the token. On reloading the page if your model is empty check the local storage and incase that is empty to redirect the user.  Else you can continue the session

Comment: yes, i tried to store the token in the local session object and found out that when i reload the page it was null, after that i again set the token , but still the User object is null. I think we have to set something else for Oauth protocol or GAE User object which is injected into the endpoint methods defaultly.Either i have to route it differently or handle the refresh for oauth and GAE proporly. I am out of solutions. Please help me out on this.

Comment: After you store it, on load you also need to load it back into the model at the time of page load. Why don't you post your code to plunkr or fiddle?

Comment: Thank you Shouvik for the comments and help. Your comments made me think that i was going in the right direction. Thank you

Comment: Glad that it work out

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone, i was using session storage in Angular JS to store my access_token and was trying to retrieve the same when refreshing the page, but there was a syntax problem when i was setting the toke for the gapi.client API. Below is the sample code to store and retrieve.
//To sotre the access_token
`sessionStorage.setItem(                                                                        "accesstoken",gapi.auth .getToken().access_token);`
To retrieve and set it back

```
var persistedval = sessionStorage
                            .getItem("accesstoken");
                    if (persistedval) {
                        gapi.auth.setToken({access_token :persistedval});
                        console.log(gapi.auth.getToken().access_token);
                        oauth2Provider.signedIn = true;
                    }
```

The main thing is to note the syntax of setToken. Thank you